# maven test report format

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, groovy, maven-surefire-plugin

When I run the tests In my Java/Groovy Maven project, the test reports are stored in `target/surefire-reports`. For each test class that is run a `.txt` and `.xml` file is created showing the output of that class.

All in all, this is a remarkably unhelpful format, as it doesn't provide any easy way to quickly see which tests failed and the output they produced. I'd like something similar to Grails' test reports. Is there are any easy way to change the report format to something more user friendly?

Ideally, I'd like this report to be generated when I run `mvn test`, i.e. I'd prefer not to have to run `mvn site` to generate it.

Comment: I agree that the console output is hard to read. I got spoiled using ScalaTest as that output is super nice. I would like to see the same for Java.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the Maven Surefire Report plugin to generating the unit testing report. The web site is http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin

My POM looks like the following: -

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </reporting>
```

I hope this may help to achieve your requirement.

//Edit: I also use the CI server, the Jenkins, which provides the unit testing report as well.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: This is the standard maven approach to generating a "pretty" test report. +1

Answer (score 0):

Sort the folder by size in ascending order. Biggest `.txt` files are the output of failed tests.

Comment: That will help a little, but it's still really annoying to have to open several different .txt/.xml files to see all the information I need about failing tests.

Comment: Agree, but it's a time saver. Usually it's much faster finding and opening the largest `.txt` file than waiting for the test report site generation, opening it and looking for the failed tests. Anything that can speedup the loop develop/test/run is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is an HTML report plugin ([here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)), but not sure this is what you want. If you need something more specific, I guess you'll need to develop your own Maven plugin.