# Maven report on all tests on method level

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I want to generate a report after maven runs the tests that will display a list of all tests that are run. I don't want the tests to be grouped by class, I just want a list of executed tests. For example if I have

```
class Test1 {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
  }
}

class Test2 {
  @Test
  public void test2() {
  }
}
```

After running the tests I want a report that looks like:

Test1.test1  PASSED time:2sec

Test2.test2  FAILED time:1sec

Is there a maven report plugin that does this or any other way that this can be done?

I've looked at [maven test report format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503895/maven-test-report-format) but it seems there you have to click class by class to see the failing methods.

I would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I researched the documentation for both SureFire and [Cobertura](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/index.html), and there does not appear to be a built-in report in the format you seek.

However, the file `TEST-TestSuite.xml` generated by SureFire will contain an entry for every individual test case at the method-level. So, your best bet is to develop a trivial XML transform that converts this file to the format you prefer.